# ST_3DSnap... add 3D Point to 3D Polygon

Tags: polygon, point, 3d

ST_Snap just work in 2D...
It is possible to add a 3D Point to 3D Polygon? ST_3DSnap :(
Or add ST_3DClosestPoint to polygon.

SELECT DISTINCT ST_Snap(a.geom, b.geom, 0.001) as geom. 2D only.

Comment: I don't understand what the question is. You mention ST_3DClosestPoint. That should handle polygons in 3d.

Comment: Hello Nicklas, I just need to add one boundary intersection 3d point to 3d polygon. Thanks